# JQuery return date value changes

Tags: jquery

```
$.post('includes/api_orderupdate.php', { getupate:1, ship:id, country:country, state:state, subtotal:subtotal  },
    function(data){ 
      var updateval=data.split('~~');
      $('#ship_info').text(updateval[0].trim());
      var taxdet=updateval[1];
      alert(taxdet);

    });
```

and my output is:

```
<input type='hidden' class='taxinfo' value='VAT:237.5'><input type='hidden' class='taxinfo' value='supertax:220'>
```

How to get this value only like VAT:237.5, supertax:220

I don't know how to get the value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it just `.val()`? http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you would like to retrieve the `value` attribute of each `input` element:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always `map` them:

```
var values = $('input').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(', ');

console.log(values); // VAT:237.5, supertax:220
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QRHyc/